# React Native | react-native-iap

Tags: react-native, in-app-billing, react-native-iap

It is the first time that I use react-native-iap in my project. I installed the library without any problems. I have a few questions.

1. My code block is below for a single product purchase. Is this usage right now?

```
import * as RNIap from 'react-native-iap';

const itemSkus = Platform.select({
    ios: ['stackoverflow_ex'],
    android: ['stackoverflow_ex']
});

export default class Buy extends Component {

    state= {
        products:[],
        count:0
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const products: Product[] = await RNIap.getProducts(itemSkus);
            this.setState({ products });
        } catch(err) {
            console.warn(err); // standardized err.code and err.message available
        }
    }

    requestPurchase = async (sku: string) => {
        try {
            await RNIap.requestPurchase(sku, false);
            this.setState({ count:this.state.count+1 });
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err.code, err.message);
        }
    }

    click = () => {
        this.requestPurchase('stackoverflow_ex') 
    }

    render() {
        const {item} = this.props;
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.click()} />
        );
    }
}
```

2. How do I get a return from the 'RNIap.requestPurchase (sku, false)' function? For example: const result = RNIap.requestPurchase (sku, false);
3. The above code works to a certain extent for IOS. Clicking 'Apple Home Page' comes to the payment process. Nothing happens after filling it there. Not doing in Count + 1. Is it because it says 'Ready to Submit' next to the product I added to Apple Connect? Will Apple approve this product? Should I wait for him?
4. Products are coming in iOS. The empty list on Android is returning. Should I upload it to open beta and try it?

Comment: Hello, were you able to get "products" on app side even "Ready to Submit" was written on itunes ?

Answer (score 1):

For `android` you need to upload your `apk` in Google play. if not then you cannot test Google play billing in your application. What you can do is upload the `apk` and do a release under `Internal test track`. It will take 2-3 days for the review process. After that you can do the testing.

For more read please check this [link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test)

Answer (score 0):

From the first glance, I would say that at least `initConnection` is missing.
The best way to make sure the code is done correctly check out example in the github: https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap/blob/master/IapExample/App.js